# Django rest-framework with GenericViewSet: Filter results base on query parameters from the url

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, redux-saga

My application is using GenericViewSet with ListModelMixin. I have used `filter_backends` and `filter_class` to filter out results. (see **'list': serializers.BookingListSerializer** from screenshot below)

[image]

I am working on the following brief:

Let's say I have a list of animals which are pre-filtered (using `filter_backends`) and then shown on UI to the user.

1. Users can further filter results based on some search criteria from UI (let's say name, type, color). These filterations are handled by `filter_class`.
2. In a separate Tab on UI which only shows animals of type *Dogs* rather than the entire collection of animals. And which can again be filtered further based on the name & color.

I must create 2 separate end-points to show both kinds of results to the user (to have more control over results...ya screw DRY!). But I can't figure out how to create them in Django as both `animals` and `dogs` use the same django modal and the filter backends and filter class are applied only to the actual modal ie. on the list of animals.

I need simple `def list1(request)` and `def list2(request)` where I can filter the `query_set` based on request params and my filter backends and filter classes.

**api.py**

```
class BookingViewSet(
MultipleSerializerMixin,
mixins.CreateModelMixin,
mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
mixins.ListModelMixin,
viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
lookup_field = 'uuid'
queryset = models.Booking.objects.all()
permission_classes = [DRYPermissions, ]
filter_backends = [filters.BookingFilterBackend, DjangoFilterBackend, ]
filter_class = filters.BookingFilter
pagination_class = BookingViewSetPagination
serializer_class = serializers.BookingDetailSerializer

serializer_classes = {
    'create': serializers.BookingCreateUpdateSerializer,
    'update': serializers.BookingCreateUpdateSerializer,
    'duplicate': serializers.BookingCreateUpdateSerializer,
    'list': serializers.BookingListSerializer,
    'list_drafts': serializers.BookingListSerializer,
    'create_draft': serializers.BookingCreateUpdateSerializer,
    'submit_draft': serializers.BookingCreateUpdateSerializer,
}

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    booking = services.create_booking(serializer.validated_data)
    data = serializers.BookingDetailSerializer(booking, context={'request': request}).data

    return response.Created(data)

def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    booking = self.get_object()

    partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(booking, data=request.data, partial=partial)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    booking = services.update_booking(booking, serializer.validated_data)

    async('shootsta.bookings.tasks.booking_update_google_calendar_event', booking.pk)

    data = serializers.BookingDetailSerializer(booking, context={'request': request}).data

    return response.Ok(data)

@detail_route(methods=['POST'], url_path='duplicate')
def duplicate(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    booking = self.get_object()

    new_booking = services.duplicate_booking(booking)

    data = serializers.BookingDetailSerializer(new_booking, context={'request': request}).data

    return response.Created(data)

@list_route(methods=['GET'], url_path='list-drafts')
def list_drafts(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Code goes here! Here i'll get some params from url like state and title and then return filtered the results.
    pass

@list_route(methods=['POST'], url_path='create-draft')
def create_draft(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    booking = services.create_booking(serializer.validated_data, constants.BookingMode.draft)
    data = serializers.BookingDetailSerializer(booking, context={'request': request}).data

    return response.Created(data)

@detail_route(methods=['POST'], url_path='submit-draft')
def submit_draft(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    booking = self.get_object()
    booking.submit_draft(by=request.user)
    booking.save()

    data = serializers.BookingDetailSerializer(booking, context={'request': request}).data

    return response.Ok(data)

@detail_route(methods=['POST'], url_path='approve')
def approve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    booking = self.get_object()
    booking.approve(by=request.user)
    booking.save()

    data = serializers.BookingDetailSerializer(booking, context={'request': request}).data

    return response.Ok(data)
```

**filters.py**

```
# Standard Library
import operator
from functools import reduce

# Third Party
from django.db.models import Q
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from dry_rest_permissions.generics import DRYPermissionFiltersBase

# Project Local
from . import models


class BookingFilterBackend(DRYPermissionFiltersBase):
    def filter_list_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        if request.user.is_role_admin:
            return queryset

        if request.user.is_role_client:
            return queryset.filter(Q(client=request.user.client))

        if request.user.is_role_camop:
            return queryset.filter(Q(camera_operator=request.user))

        return queryset.filter(Q(created_by=request.user))


def filter_booking_title(queryset, name, value):
    """
    Split the filter value into separate search terms and construct a set of queries from this. The set of queries
    includes an icontains lookup for the lookup fields for each of the search terms. The set of queries is then joined
    with the OR operator.
    """
    lookups = ['title__icontains', ]

    or_queries = []

    search_terms = value.split()

    for search_term in search_terms:
        or_queries += [Q(**{lookup: search_term}) for lookup in lookups]

    return queryset.filter(reduce(operator.or_, or_queries))


class BookingFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    title = filters.CharFilter(method=filter_booking_title)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Booking
        fields = [
            'title',
            'state',
            'client',
        ]
```

Comment: Why did you add a screenshot rather than code snippet?

Comment: @JPG because the code formatting was messed up and there is nothing else relatable to my issue other than this piece of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class SampleViewset(.....):

    @list_route(methods=['GET'])
    def list_2(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        myqueryset = MyModel.objects.all() # or whatever queryset you need to serialize
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(myqueryset)

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**The key points you should notice here are,**
1. The filtering process are being excecuted inside the [**`self.filter_queryset()`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#filter_querysetself-queryset) method, which return a **`QuerySet`** after filter applied.
2. You could use **`self.get_queryset()`** method in place of **`myqueryset = MyModel.objects.all()`** staement, which is the ***DRF Way*** of doing such things

**UPDATE-1**
If you want to use the default `queryset` , you could use the **`get_queryset()`** method as,

```
class SampleViewset(.....):

    @list_route(methods=['GET'])
    def list_2(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**or simply,**

```
class SampleViewset(.....):

    @list_route(methods=['GET'])
    def list_2(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'm using `@list_route` and `@detail_route` decorators instead. But I can't understand how can I use `filter_backends` and `filter_class` on such custom methods.

Comment: You should add your view, so that I could help you more

Comment: Attached relevant files. Please check.

Comment: @saran3h Update the answer. Take a look at the notes I've mentioned

Comment: Yes,this is almost exactly what I did and it worked perfectly. However, i still have to use my filter_backends and filter_class on the same queryset.

Is there anyway i can do - `self.filter_queryset(myqueryset, self.filter_backend)` ?

Comment: Is this **`myqueryset`** is same as the **`queryset`** attribute in your ***View class*** ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same.

Comment: Then what would be difference between the `list_2()` and the default list api ?

Comment: list_2() will have every filter applied to default list (via filter_backends) PLUS more filterations coming from different url params.

I could've just extended my original filters on default api But I don't want these additional filters to mess the results of default list api. Also, i need more control on how the two lists behave.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite get the question but I think you should do the same thing on your custom action that DRF does on its generic list. just call `filter_queryset` on your initial query for example:

```
class your_view(....):
...
...
    def get_queryset2(self):
        return YourotherModel.objects.all() ### or any thing your i.e. specific fiter on your general model


    @action(methods=['GET'], detail=False)
    def list2(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset2()) ### call filter_queryset on your custom query

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```